# JW Player not working in kitkat version webview

Tags: android, jwplayer

The following error code appears.
i remember very well working in ver jwplayer sdk 2.4.2 .
after jwplayer sdk updated to ver2.7.1. It don't work play just in kitkat.
jwplayer is very well working in other version (5.0.6.0.7.0 android os)
What should I do? help me please.

error :

```
? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.d.h', referenced from method com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.core.i.a
? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.d.j', referenced from method com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.core.i.a
? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.d.l', referenced from method com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.core.i.a
```

Comment: jwplayer sdk need support flash try it with flash,it's working.

Comment: can you add your manifest code here. that could be more helpful to identify the issue.